# maven dependency version?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven. i have a project and it has a pom. inside the pom there is a dependency as below:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-project</artifactId>
        <version>${originalVersion}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My question is where is ${originalVersion} value coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: It must be in 1 of your other config files.

Comment: The value is probably defined in a properties tag.  Check to see if your pom has a parent tag.  If it does, the properties will probably be defined in that pom, or in it's parent pom etc...

Comment: If you have a parent the usual thing is to use ${project.version} but i'm not sure, cause i can't see the complete pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`originalVersion` is not a standard Maven property so it must appear elsewhere such as in a parent pom, like this:

```
<properties>
    <originalVersion>1.2</originalVersion>
</properties>
```

See [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Answer (score 4):

It is either defined [somewhere else in the pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), in a [parent-pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) (there can be several of those, because parents can have parents too), or via a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) (that might be defined somewhere else, like your [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)). It could also have been passed as [a command-line parameter](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) to maven, but you'd probably have noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from a property in your pom.xml.
Something like that:

```
<properties>
   <originalVersion>1.0</originalVersion>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a `<properties>` section in the pom.xml file, there must be a entry like `<originalVersion>...</originalVersion>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `properties` sub section on the [maven tutorial page](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation). It says, following are the possible ways to reference a vairable

> 1. env.X: Prefixing a variable with "env." will return the shell's environment variable. For example, ${env.PATH} contains the $path
>      environment variable (%PATH% in Windows).
> 2. project.x: A dot (.) notated path in the POM will contain the corresponding element's value. For example:
>      1.0 is accessible via
>      ${project.version}.
> 3. settings.x: A dot (.) notated path in the settings.xml will contain the corresponding element's value. For example:
>      false is accessible via
>      ${settings.offline}.
> 4. Java System Properties: All properties accessible via java.lang.System.getProperties() are available as POM properties, such
>      as ${java.home}.
> 5. x: Set within a  element or an external files, the value may be used as ${someVar}.